# Always open a particular folder in a specific view

Tags: mojave

I went to the folder /Users/username and `right click the Desktop folder -> selected show view options -> ticked Always open in icon view, browse in icon view`

Now I closed the popup and `manually changed the view of Desktop folder to list view` and closed the folder and opened a new finder window again. I expected the Desktop folder to be opened in icon view but it is still opening in `list` view

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `View > Show view options (Cmd+J)`: `Always open in...`. This option changes according to the view mode of the folder. You can still change the view mode after checking this option and whichever you activate will persist.

Comment: @Joonas: Thanks, I got confused earlier. The checkbox should have been named as `Enable Persisting of a selected view` instead of showing the text as 'Always open in icon view' which lead to the confusion